Print page with a background color starting at the PDF document's edge
I would like the gray and blue box to be aligned to the edge of the PDF generated by Google Chrome via the print dialog.

@page is size: letter portrait or 8.5" (w) x 11" (h)
left-sidebar is height: 11in with a blue background
intro is height: 2in with a gray background

Why doesn't this work? Is it possible to prevent the white background from appearing at the top / left / bottom of left-sidebar div?

Code
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        /* Printing */
        * {
            /* Force background graphic printing */
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;   /* Chrome, Safari 6 – 15.3, Edge */
            color-adjust: exact !important;                 /* Firefox 48 – 96 */
            print-color-adjust: exact !important;           /* Firefox 97+, Safari 15.4+ */
        }
        @page {
            size: letter portrait;
            margin: 0;
        }
        @media print {
            body {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            .page {
                visibility: visible;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        }

        /* Browser */
        @media screen {
            body {
                background: #e0e0e0;
            }
            .page {
                background: white;
                box-shadow: 0 .5mm 2mm rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                margin: 2rem auto;
            }
        }

        /* Paging */
        *, *:before, *:after {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .page {
            width: 8.5in;
            height: 11in;
        }
        .page-content {
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
        }

        /* Page Layout */
        .left-sidebar {
            flex-grow: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            width: 3in;
            height: 11in !important;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #284877;
            color: white;
        }
        .right-sidebar {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
        }
        .intro {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 2in;
            background-color: #d2d2d2;
        }

        /* Text */
        .title {
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #284877;
            font-size: 24pt;
        }
        .section {
            padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="left-sidebar">
                <div class="intro">
                    <div class="title">
                        Document Name
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="section">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum 1...</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-sidebar">
                <p>Lorem ipsum 2...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

Live demo: https://ajility.dev/stack-overflow/print-with-bleed/

You have most of the correct HTML coding for the desired page but slightly the wrong command order. PDF pages have no margins and thus the Page Body /MediaBox and /BleedBox need to be the same size, without borders, margins, padding or shadow box.
Here is a temporary link to the result of changing a line or two.
https://filetransfer.io/data-package/L6EUUb1S#link
Here is the view.

Here is the start of Media Page <style> for that result.
<style>
        /* Printing */
        * {
            /* Force background graphic printing */
            -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;   /* Chrome, Safari 6 – 15.3, Edge */
            color-adjust: exact !important;                 /* Firefox 48 – 96 */
            print-color-adjust: exact !important;           /* Firefox 97+, Safari 15.4+ */
        }
        @media print { @ page {size: letter; margin: 0;}
            body {
                visibility: hidden; margin: 0;
            }
            .page {
                visibility: visible;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
        }

This ensures there is only one boundary (/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]) for the PDF page.
<<
  /Type /Page
  /Resources <</ExtGState <</G3 3 0 R/G4 4 0 R>>/Font <</F5 5 0 R>> >>
  /MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
  /Contents 6 0 R
  /StructParents 0
  /Parent 7 0 R
>>


You are awesome - thanks! Can I know what is the 2nd block of code in your answer called (/MediaBox...)? I have never seen that before.
